# finding flights with flexible origination points

Tags: air-travel

I will be wandering in Europe and flying back to Chicago on a one way ticket.  I will adjust my trip to end up in the city I fly home from.  I don't care if it's Paris or Berlin or Barcelona or any other city.  Looking for a good deal.

Any hints on how to search for this kind of information without checking every city individually?  Kinda like a googleflights display but for originations instead of destination.

Comment: Nope. One ways are ... special.

Comment: @chx: I'm not sure what you're saying "nope" to. It's certainly possible to do the exact type of search the OP is asking about, and answers to the question I linked as a duplicate tell how.